# Reading from a file to a vector

Tags: c++, file, class, vector, stdmap

I'm reading from file with the data below. What I need to achieve is at the end populating the vector m_hoteli with CHotel objects which have CTurist objects. 2nd-5th row are hotels with their variables and after the big numbers(500,400,300,600), that's the tourists in each hotel.

When I run it, my vectors gets filled with the information from the file but fills the details about the tourists as hotel data, thus I can't make a proper connection between the input and CTurist.

> Marina 5 500 Joe 21 1 Tisho 20 6 Victoria 31 20
>
> Tulip 4 400 Sarah 41 17 Rositsa 49 14 Valeria 24 2
>
> BlackSea 3 300 John 35 12 Jon 35 11 Janni 28 6
>
> SwissBell 5 600 Orlin 26 1 Margarita 27 2 Juliette 31

```
class CComplex:CHotel
{

protected:
    string m_complex;
    vector<CHotel> m_hoteli;
public:
    CComplex(){};

CComplex(string filename, string nComplex)
{
    string str;
    m_complex = nComplex;
    fstream file(filename, ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        CHotel temp(" ", 0, 0);
        while (file >> temp)
        {
            m_hoteli.push_back(temp);

        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
        throw "ERROR! ";
        }
```

CHotel(String stringname) constructor:

```
class CHotel : public CTurist          //втори клас, наследник на CTurist
{
protected:

    string hName;    //име хотел
    int stars;          //звезди на хотела
    int beds;           //брой легла

public:
    map<CTurist, unsigned> Turisti; 
        unsigned Sum = 0;
    int br = 0;
    CHotel(){};
    CHotel(string s)
        {
            map<CTurist, unsigned> TR;

            bool first = true;
            istringstream TList(s);
            int i = 0;

            while (getline(TList, s, ' '))
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case 0: this->setName(s); break;
                case 1: this->setAge(stoi(s)); break;
                }

                if (i ==2 )
                {
                    if (!first){ setName(getName()); setAge(getAge()); first = true; }
                    else{ TR[CTurist("", 0)]; }
                    i = -1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Turisti = TR;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the file is opened. I'll make a check though, noted.

My problem is when I'm reading the file I can't find out how to access CTurist and the input operator of it so as a result in my vector I'm writing the Tourists as Hotels.

Comment: Groovy. So the problem is you have no good way for the parser to tell tourist from hotel? If I'm reading you right, you want to `getline` an entire line, then split that line. The first couple tokens on the line are the hotel and the rest are the people staying at the hotel, yes?

Comment: @user4581301 Exactly. I have posted a new code which i've updated which I think is close to correct,but still gives me some troubles. If you could have a look, that'd be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

That's some advancement I think I have made on the constructor. Looking through the breakpoints, the hotel receives it's information,aka name, stars and beds, but the tourists do not. Any tips?
  CHotel(string s)
    {

```
    CTurist b("",0);
    bool first = true;

    istringstream TList(s);

    string Days;
    int i = 0;
    string ime;
    string godini;

    if (first == true)
    {

    while (getline(TList, s, ' '))
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: this->hName = s; break;
        case 1:this->stars = stoi(s); break;
        case 2:this->beds = stoi(s); break;

        }
        i++;
        if (i == 3)break;

    }
    first = false;
    i = 0;
}
    while (getline(TList, s, '|'))
    {
        switch (i)
        {

        case 0: ime = s; break;
        case 1: godini = s; break;
        case 2: Days = s; break;


        }
        i++;
        if (i == 3)
        {
            CTurist T1("ime", stoi(Days));
            //Turisti.insert(pair<CTurist,unsigned>("ime", stoi(Days))); 


                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to insert T1 into mapTuristi???